# iOS 8 notification action button not displayed

Tags: ios, button, uilocalnotification

I am trying to send a local notification with a action button.
The notification is ok. But the action button is not displayed.
I am using Xcode 6.3.2 iPhone 6 iOS 8.2

---

Sending notification

```
UIApplication *myapp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UILocalNotification *test = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

if(test) {
    NSLog(@"Sending notification");

    test.alertBody = @"jothi test alert";
    test.alertTitle = @"kottapa";

    test.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    test.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"View Details", nil);
    test.category = @"MY_CATEGORY";

    [myapp presentLocalNotificationNow:test];
}
```

---

in app delegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
UIMutableUserNotificationAction *myAction =
[[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];

myAction.identifier = @"MY_IDENTIFIER";        
myAction.title = @"Test Action";
myAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground;
myAction.destructive = NO;
myAction.authenticationRequired = NO;

//------------

// First create the category
UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *inviteCategory =
   [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];

// Identifier to include in your push payload and local notification
inviteCategory.identifier = @"MY_CATEGORY";

// Add the actions to the category and set the action context
[inviteCategory setActions:@[myAction]
                forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];

// Set the actions to present in a minimal context
[inviteCategory setActions:@[myAction]
                forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextMinimal];

NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObject:inviteCategory];

UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound
                                      categories:categories];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
```

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32239012/actions-and-categories-dont-show-in-uilocalnotification-in-ios/33072727#33072727

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works, you just needs to swipe the notification to the left in order to see the action button (or pull it down, if it's presented in a form of a banner from the top, when the device isn't locked).

Also, I'm guessing you already did that but just didn't include the code, in order to handle the action the user chose, you need to implement this method in your app delegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Why should it be like this. Does all user knows they need to swipe right?. My opinion it should display the button in visible area